# URI 1036 (beecrowd 1036) BHASKARA

Tags: javascript

So, i'm kinda new on JavaScript and i got stuck on an exercise from Beecrowd (exercise number 1036).

Here is the exercise

> Read 3 floating-point numbers. After, print the roots of bhaskara’s
> formula. If it's impossible to calculate the roots because a division
> by zero or a square root of a negative number, presents the message
> “Impossivel calcular”.
>
> Input
>
> Read 3 floating-point numbers (double) A, B and C.
>
> Output
>
> Print the result with 5 digits after the decimal point or the message
> if it is impossible to calculate.

link to the exercise: https://www.beecrowd.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1036

And here is my code - Anyone know what is wrong with it

```js
const input = `10.0
20.1 
5.1`
// R1 = -0.29788
// R2 = -1.71212
/*
    0.0 20.0 5.0
// Impossivel calcular
    10.3 203.0 5.0
// R1 = -0.02466
// R2 = -19.68408
    10.0 3.0 5.0
// Impossivel calcular

    */

// var input = require('fs').readFileSync('/dev/stdin', 'utf8');
var lines = input.split('\n');

/**
 * Escreva a sua solução aqui
 * Code your solution here
 * Escriba su solución aquí
 */

let a = parseFloat(lines.shift());
let b = parseFloat(lines.shift());
let c = parseFloat(lines.shift());

let delta = b * b - 4 * a * c;



if (delta < 0 || a === 0 || delta === 0) {
  console.log("Impossivel calcular");
} else {
  let r1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
  let r2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
  console.log('R1 = ' + r1.toFixed(5));
  console.log('R2 = ' + r2.toFixed(5));
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is *the* problem, but it's definitely *a* problem - a delta of 0 is perfectly fine. In this case you'll have just one root, not two.

Comment: broken "b" is "l" and "c"

Comment: I made you another snippet. The first set of values give what the question shows as expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work just fine

Here is a simpler version

```js
// var input = require('fs').readFileSync('/dev/stdin', 'utf8');

const input = `10.0 20.1 5.1
0.0 20.0 5.0
10.3 203.0 5.0
10.0 3.0 5.0`

input.split('\n').forEach(line => {
  let [a, b, c] = line.split(" ").map(str => +str);
  let delta = b * b - 4 * a * c;
  if (delta <= 0 || a === 0) {
    console.log("Impossivel calcular");
    return;
  }
  let r1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
  let r2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
  console.log('R1 = ' + r1.toFixed(5));
  console.log('R2 = ' + r2.toFixed(5));
});
```

```html
<pre>
    10.0 20.1 5.1
    // R1 = -0.29788
    // R2 = -1.71212

    0.0 20.0 5.0
    // Impossivel calcular

    10.3 203.0 5.0
    // R1 = -0.02466
    // R2 = -19.68408

    10.0 3.0 5.0
    // Impossivel calcular

 </pre>
```